# How can I fit a 10x4 register in this space?

Tags: hvac, ceiling, register

I have a shallow ceiling and I'm trying to figure out how to fit a 10"x4" vent into the ceiling tile. When the vent is open, it is about 1.5" high or more. That would take up all the available space left by itself. Is there some other 6" T that opens up to a 10x4 rectangle instead of a 6" circle?

[image: distant view]
[image: close up]

Comment: Have you considered a round vent, I think that would look great and be a lot less work.

Comment: If I have to do that, I will, but as you can see, I'm right next to a wall so I'd rather the air be aimed into the room rather than at the wall

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did when I finished my basement. Remove that TEE and replace it with 6"round flex duct. Install a 4x10x6 straight register boot into the tile. You may not be able to find a 4x10x6 register boot and may need to up size to a 6x10x6 boot. By the way, you can't add 2 registers to one 6" round duct and get a good air flow from both. A 6" round duct can only supply one register. You may need to barrow a duct crimper to complete this task and get the flex onto the end of that duct.

Comment: Good info. I didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

The supply pipe looks like it ends at that outlet. The buy an "end boot." They can be inline type or cross type. They come in 3 x 10 and 4 x 10 sizes. Remove the T fitting and install the end boot. The rectangular flange can be trimmed back if needed.

Comment: I actually have two T's, I just didn't show the other one. If I really had to though I could negate two T's and center just one register in the room. Not ideal though

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Saddle Tee**

You could replace that regular tee with a saddle tee.

You'll just have to cut it low enough that the register boot still has something to hold on to. You'll probably end up with a lot of tape.

[image]

---

**Option 2: Wye with a 45 elbow to a boot**

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Option 3: Custom fabrication**

If you have a local HVAC supplier or sheet-metal shop you can ask them if they can fabricate what you desire. It will like cost 4-5x the cost of your current tee but could be worth it to have exactly the right part =)